# How to access a file inside the public folder in Quasar from the URL?

Tags: file, public, quasar

I want to open the form that is located inside the public folder.
structure is like that:

```
-public
----icons
----form.pdf
-src
```

I tried http://localhost:8080/public/form.pdf, but it says : `Cannot GET /public/form.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is by accessing with this url `http://localhost:8080/form.pdf`